# PL-SQL - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Trying to loop through a sysrefcursor but getting `ORA-00932` seems like when looping, the dates, e.g.: `1990/01/01`  get operated on as if they were a division ?

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
    email VARCHAR2(1000);
    webcastEngagement NUMBER(10,1);
    videoEngagement NUMBER(10,1);
    documentEngagement NUMBER(10,1);
    totalEngagement NUMBER(10,1);
    --averageEngagement NUMBER(4,1);
    totalWebcastSeconds NUMBER(10);
    engagementMinutes NUMBER(10, 1);
    last30DaysEM NUMBER(10, 1);
    last60DaysEM NUMBER(10, 1);
    fromDate DATE;
    engagementPrediction NUMBER(10);
    engagementLevel VARCHAR2(6 CHAR);
    totalWebcasts NUMBER(10);
    totalVideos NUMBER(10);
    totalDocuments NUMBER(10);
    totalURLs NUMBER(10);
    firstName VARCHAR2(1000);
    lastName VARCHAR2(1000);
    company VARCHAR2(1000);
    jobTitle VARCHAR2(1000);
    workPhone VARCHAR2(1000);
    clientName VARCHAR2(1000);
    portalEnabled VARCHAR2(5);
    resources NUMBER(10);
    videoProfile NUMBER;
    showInterestCloud VARCHAR2(10);
    attended VARCHAR(1);
    leadIndex NUMBER := 1;
    clientFunnelStages VARCHAR2(4000);
    funnelStage VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
    partnerref VARCHAR2(4000);
    experienceProfileId NUMBER := 525;
    resp    ON24MASTER.WEBCAST_REPORTS.ResultSetCursor;
BEGIN
    resp := WEBCAST_REPORTS.LEAD_BASIC_INFO('testqa_11071113@inbfw.com',22917);
    LOOP
        FETCH resp into email, webcastEngagement,videoEngagement,documentEngagement, totalEngagement,totalWebcastSeconds,engagementMinutes,last30DaysEM,last60DaysEM, 
                        fromDate,-- also tried to_date(fromDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                        engagementPrediction,engagementLevel,totalWebcasts, totalVideos, totalDocuments, totalURLs, firstName,lastName,company, jobTitle,workPhone,
                        clientName,portalEnabled,resources,videoProfile,showInterestCloud,attended,leadIndex,clientFunnelStages,funnelStage,partnerref,experienceProfileId;

        dbms_output.put_line(email|| ' ---- ' || webcastEngagement|| ' ---- ' ||videoEngagement|| ' ---- ' ||documentEngagement|| ' ---- ' || totalEngagement|| ' ---- ' ||totalWebcastSeconds|| ' ---- ' ||engagementMinutes|| ' ---- ' ||last30DaysEM|| ' ---- ' ||last60DaysEM|| ' ---- ' ||fromDate|| ' ---- ' ||
                        engagementPrediction|| ' ---- ' ||engagementLevel|| ' ---- ' ||totalWebcasts|| ' ---- ' || totalVideos|| ' ---- ' || totalDocuments|| ' ---- ' || totalURLs|| ' ---- ' || firstName|| ' ---- ' ||lastName|| ' ---- ' ||company|| ' ---- ' || jobTitle|| ' ---- ' ||workPhone|| ' ---- ' ||
                        clientName|| ' ---- ' ||portalEnabled|| ' ---- ' ||resources|| ' ---- ' ||videoProfile|| ' ---- ' ||showInterestCloud|| ' ---- ' ||attended|| ' ---- ' ||leadIndex|| ' ---- ' ||clientFunnelStages|| ' ---- ' ||funnelStage|| ' ---- ' ||partnerref|| ' ---- ' ||experienceProfileId);
    exit when resp%notfound;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE resp;
END;
/
```

in function body,  `fromDate DATE` does very simple things, it will be assigned similar to: `fromDate := SYSDATE - 60`

My goal is to output the result set.

What currently works, has horrible output:

```
variable rc refcursor;

DECLARE
  LEADEMAIL VARCHAR2(200);
  CLIENTID NUMBER;
BEGIN
  LEADEMAIL := 'nunyo@business.com';
  CLIENTID := 22921;

  :rc := WEBCAST_REPORTS.LEAD_BASIC_INFO(
    LEADEMAIL => LEADEMAIL,
    CLIENTID => CLIENTID
  );

END;
/

print rc;
```

This is part of the output:

```
EMAIL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             CLIENT_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
CLIENT_NAME                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      CG_ACTIVE                        WEBCAST_ENGAGEMENT VIDEO_ENGAGEMENT DOCUMENT_ENGAGEMENT TOTAL_ENGAGEMENT AVG_WEBCAST_MINUTES  NGAGEMENT_MINUTES TOTAL_WEBCASTS
```

---

```
TOTAL_VIDEOS TOTAL_DOCUMENTS TOTAL_URLS A PREDIC LAST_30D_ENGAGEMENT_MINUTES LAST_60D_ENGAGEMENT_MINUTES ENGAGEMENT_LEVEL                 FIRST_NAME
------------ --------------- ---------- - ------ --------------------------- --------------------------- -------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAST_NAME
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JOB_TITLE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WORK_PHONE
```

---

```
COMPANY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          REGISTRATION_SOURCE              H H H H  RESOURCES S
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------- - - - - ---------- -
FUNNEL_STAGE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           0               0          0 Y HIGH                            34                          34 LOW                              test                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

EMAIL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             CLIENT_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
CLIENT_NAME
```

### Update

```
 FUNCTION LEAD_BASIC_INFO(
    leadEmail VARCHAR2,
    clientId NUMBER
  ) RETURN ResultSetCursor IS

 -- rest of the variables
 -- more code 

   OPEN resultSet FOR
      select
        nvl(email, leadEmail) EMAIL,
        clientId CLIENT_ID,
        clientName CLIENT_NAME,
        portalEnabled CG_ACTIVE,
        nvl(webcastEngagement, 0) WEBCAST_ENGAGEMENT,
        nvl(videoEngagement, 0) VIDEO_ENGAGEMENT,
        nvl(documentEngagement, 0) DOCUMENT_ENGAGEMENT,
        nvl(totalEngagement, 0) TOTAL_ENGAGEMENT,
        --nvl(averageEngagement, 0) AVERAGE_ENGAGEMENT,
        case when nvl(totalWebcasts, 0) = 0
          then 0
          else nvl(round((totalWebcastSeconds/totalWebcasts)/60, 1), 0)
        end AVG_WEBCAST_MINUTES,
        nvl(engagementMinutes, 0) ENGAGEMENT_MINUTES,
        nvl(totalWebcasts, 0) TOTAL_WEBCASTS,
        nvl(totalVideos, 0) TOTAL_VIDEOS,
        nvl(totalDocuments, 0) TOTAL_DOCUMENTS,
        nvl(totalURLs, 0) TOTAL_URLS,
        case when (nvl(totalWebcasts, 0) + nvl(totalVideos, 0) + nvl(totalDocuments, 0) + nvl(totalURLs, 0) > 0) then 'Y' else 'N' end ATTENDED,
        case engagementPrediction when 1 then 'LOW' when 2 then 'MEDIUM' when 3 then 'HIGH' else '' end as PREDICTIVE_ENGAGEMENT,
        last30DaysEM as LAST_30D_ENGAGEMENT_MINUTES,
        last60DaysEM as LAST_60D_ENGAGEMENT_MINUTES,
        engagementLevel as ENGAGEMENT_LEVEL,
        nvl(firstName, '') FIRST_NAME,
        nvl(lastName, '') LAST_NAME,
        nvl(jobTitle, '') JOB_TITLE,
        nvl(workPhone, '') WORK_PHONE,
        nvl(company, '') COMPANY,
        nvl(partnerref, '') REGISTRATION_SOURCE,
        case when (length(trim(firstName)) > 0 or length(trim(lastName)) > 0)
          then 'Y'
          else 'N'
        end HAS_NAME,
        case when (length(trim(jobTitle)) > 0)
          then 'Y'
          else 'N'
        end HAS_JOB_TITLE,
        case when (length(trim(workPhone)) > 0)
          then 'Y'
          else 'N'
        end HAS_WORK_PHONE,
        case when (length(trim(company)) > 0)
          then 'Y'
          else 'N'
        end HAS_COMPANY,
        nvl(resources, 0) RESOURCES,
        case when (lower(showInterestCloud) = 'yes')
          then 'Y'
          else 'N'
        end SHOW_BIS,
        funnelStage FUNNEL_STAGE
      from dual;

    RETURN resultSet;
  END LEAD_BASIC_INFO;
```

Comment: Pleas post signature of `MY_PACKAGE.FUNCTION('somval')`

Comment: What's the type of the column? Does the function do something with the values or just select?

Comment: Your `fetch` command is missing a semicolon, and the loop is missing an `exit`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson  typed off memory, will update now

Comment: A working test case would help a lot.

Comment: If you want help figuring out why your code isn't working, post your actual code. Not something from memory, or that you made up to show what it's like, but your actual copied and pasted code. As you can see, typing something else in can introduce other errors. It's a waste of both our time and yours when you don't provide your actual code.

Comment: @KenWhite On it.

Comment: It sounds like the variable order in your `fetch into`  might not match the column order in the select list, in the query inside your function. I'd start by double-checking that.

Comment: @AlexPoole triple checked, it's the 10th in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fetch into is expecting a date in the 10th column:

```
FETCH resp into email,  -- 1
  webcastEngagement,    -- 2
  videoEngagement,      -- 3
  documentEngagement,   -- 4
  totalEngagement,      -- 5
  totalWebcastSeconds,  -- 6
  engagementMinutes,    -- 7
  last30DaysEM,         -- 8
  last60DaysEM,         -- 9
  fromDate,             -- 10
  ...
```

The 10th column in your function's query is a number:

```
   OPEN resultSet FOR
      select
        nvl(email, leadEmail) EMAIL,                                    -- 1
        clientId CLIENT_ID,                                             -- 2
        clientName CLIENT_NAME,                                         -- 3
        portalEnabled CG_ACTIVE,                                        -- 4
        nvl(webcastEngagement, 0) WEBCAST_ENGAGEMENT,                   -- 5
        nvl(videoEngagement, 0) VIDEO_ENGAGEMENT,                       -- 6
        nvl(documentEngagement, 0) DOCUMENT_ENGAGEMENT,                 -- 7
        nvl(totalEngagement, 0) TOTAL_ENGAGEMENT,                       -- 8
        --nvl(averageEngagement, 0) AVERAGE_ENGAGEMENT,                 
        case when nvl(totalWebcasts, 0) = 0
          then 0
          else nvl(round((totalWebcastSeconds/totalWebcasts)/60, 1), 0)
        end AVG_WEBCAST_MINUTES,                                        -- 9
        nvl(engagementMinutes, 0) ENGAGEMENT_MINUTES,                   -- 10
        ...
```

The two lists of columns/variables seem to be in completely different orders. For instance, `WEBCAST_ENGAGEMENT` is the fifth column in your query, but second in your fetch.

Fetch is positional - it doesn't matter what the result set columns are called (or if they are aliased at all), you have to fetch them into the variables in the same order they appear in the query's select list.

You don't actually seem to have any date columns in your query, called `fromDate` or anything else.

So, you are trying to fetch the number supplied in the query's 10th column, the `nvl()` that's aliased as `ENGAGEMENT_MINUTES`, into the date variable `fromDate`. Hence the error - expected DATE (because that's how `fromDate` is declared) got NUMBER (because that's what `ENGAGEMENT_MINUTES` is).

Comment: is it possible to CAST all columns in the result set to a string so there's no need to worry about data types ?

Comment: You could just declare all your local variables as strings. Not usually a good idea but as you're only implicitly converting them all to strings for the string concatenation inside `put_line` anyway, it doesn't really matter in this scenario.

Comment: 06504. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match"

Comment: That usually actually means you have different numbers of columns in the query and fetch, unhelpfully. Declaring all the local variables in the anonymous block as strings (varchar2) works when the number of columns matches.